# Inputting tables from the file

Tags: c++, fileinputstream

I am a beginner in C++. I want to make a database, currently I am working on one of the first features of it. I want the database to take users input and extract it to file (which works fine) and then I want it to display the numbers that were saved. How do i extract the data? I am aware that currently what I have done in the displayAll function makes no sense but I tried some other ways but could not find a working solution. How do I attach each input to a specific index of a table? Is the way I am inputting the data now doing that for me?

I realise current way I initialize the table is not optimal, my goal is to keep the value attribute, on top of that, I want to soon add the feature of a student with studentID, first name and surname in the same format as the numbers (structure) as I want it to have 2 different datatypes and be in one table with 1000 indexes.

Below is the code responsible

```
struct numbertype {
    int  value;
};
numbertype numbers[1000];


void AddNumber(){
        cout << "Input number" << endl;
        cin >> numbers[1000].value;
        ofstream numbersout;
        numbersout.open("D:\\numbers.txt", ios::app);
        numbersout << numbers[1000].value<<"\n";
        numbersout.close();
    }

    void DisplayAllNumbers(){
            ifstream numbersout("numbers.txt");
            cout << "\t\tTable: numbers";
            cout << "value" << endl;;
            while (numbersout >> numbers[1000].value){
                cout << numbers[1000].value<<endl;
            }
            numbersout.close();
        }
```

Comment: `numbers[1000]` is out of bounds

Comment: Besides the out-of-bounds array access, your file code is just fine. That said, you probably don't need either an array or a structure. A single `int` can be used to buffer the I/O: just set the int, do the file io, and repeat. More elaborate tables can be done nearly the same way with more variables.

Comment: I suggest you read up on database theory or learn to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `numbers[1000]` is invalid.  Arrays in C++ are zero-based, so the last element in a 1000-element array has the index 999.

It looks like you might be trying to use that index to push a value onto the end of the array.  It doesn't work like that.  You need to stored the size in a separate integer and maintain that.  You also need to do bounds checking to make sure you don't overflow the array.

You might find it easier to use `std::vector` instead of an array.  Vectors support dynamic growth, as well as an inbuilt size.  They are stored and accessed similar to arrays.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<numbertype> numbers;

void AddNumber()
{
    numbertype n;
    cout << "Input number" << endl;
    if (cin >> n.value) {
        numbers.push_back(n);
        ofstream numbersout("D:\\numbers.txt", ios::app);
        if( numbersout.good() ) numbersout << n.value << "\n";
    }
}

void ReadAllNumbers()
{
    numbertype n;
    ifstream numbersin("numbers.txt");
    if (numbersin.good()) {
        numbers.clear();
        while (numbersin >> n.value) {
            numbers.push_back(n);
        }
    }
}

void DisplayAllNumbers()
{
    cout << "\t\tTable: numbers";
    cout << "Wartosc" << endl;;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        cout << numbers[i].value << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really want it to be a table, you are probably right about vectors being easier for the job but I want to learn it slightly harder way before I go to easier solutions. How could I place new values from index 0 and then do the same with display?

Comment: As I said, store a value that represents your table size.  Let's call it `count` which is initialised to zero.  Assign new values at `numbers[count]`, and then increment it.  When you read your values in, reset `count` and increment it for every value you read.  Same deal.  Write to `numbers[count]`.  In both cases, make sure you don't allow any more values once `count` has reached 1000.

Comment: I went to sleep, now I attempted to implement your solution but unfortunately I was unable to make it work. Now when i try to display the numbers the program starts displaying infinite loop of first two couts in the function:(  This is how the fucntion looks like now

Answer (score 0):

I went to sleep, now I attempted to implement your solution but unfortunately I was unable to make it work. Now when I try to display the numbers the program starts displaying infinite loop of first two couts in the function:( This is how the function looks like now –

```
void Addnum(){
    int siz = 0;
    cout << "Type in the number" << endl;
    cin >> number[siz].value;
    ofstream numbersout;
    numbersout.open("D:\\numbers.txt", ios::app);
    numbersout << number[siz].value<<"\n";
    numbersout.close();
    siz++;

}


void Displaynum(){
    int siz = 0;
    cout << "\t\tTable: Numbers" << endl;;
    cout << "Value" << endl;

    ifstream numbersout("D:\\numbers.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < rozm; i++){
        numbersout >> numbersout[i].value;


    }
    numbersout.close();
}
```